# How to use relative position in c/assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, fpic

It's said **Position Independent Code** only uses relative position instead of absolute positions, how's this implemented in c and assembly respectively?

Let's take `char test[] = "string";` as an example, how to reference it by relative address?

Answer (score 2):

In C, position-independent code is a detail of the compiler's implementation. See your compiler manual to determine whether it is supported and how.

In assembly, position-independent code is a detail of the instruction set architecture. See your CPU manual to find out how to read the PC (program counter) register, how efficient that is, and what the recommended best practices are in translating a code address to a data address.

Position-relative data is less popular now that code and data are separated into different pages on most modern operating systems. It is a good way to implement self-contained executable modules, but the most common such things nowadays are viruses.

Comment: @mysql: I'm referring to data, not object code. Subroutine calls are usually PC-relative, like all jumps. (Calls into DLLs can be exceptions, though.) PIC refers to accesses to globals, see the GCC manpage or your compiler manual.

Comment: @Potatoswatter,I still don't get it,maybe a detailed question will make things clear...why does this answer say that the original solution in the question used absolute address `str`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094934/loading-raw-code-from-c-program/5095573#5095573

Comment: @mysql_go: The instruction `movl    $str, %ecx`, specifically operand `$str`, attempts to load from an absolute address. However, the linker cannot determine an address in a code segment, and therefore cannot assemble that instruction. The solution to that question implements PIC as a kind of hack. The question itself specifies the way that the string became position-independent, which is what's missing from your question. `char test[] = "string";` by itself will be allocated however the platform does it by default, which may bear no relation to PIC.

Comment: @Potatoswatter,how does it refer to that string if `$str` can't be used?

Comment: @mysql: In that question? By arranging for `$str` to immediately follow a `call` instruction so it is pushed to the stack as a return address. Note that the label `str` is not actually used at all.

Answer (score 2):

On x86, position-independent code in principle looks like this:

```
        call 1f
1:      popl %ebx
```

followed by use of `ebx` as a base pointer with a displacement equal to the distance between the data to be accessed and the address of the `popl` instruction.

In reality it's often more complicated, and typically a tiny thunk function might be used to load the PIC register like this:

```
load_ebx:
        movl 4(%esp),%ebx
        addl $some_offset,%ebx
        ret
```

where the offset is chosen such that, when the thunk returns, `ebx` contains a pointer to a designated special point in the program/library (usually the start of the global offset table), and then all subsequent `ebx`-relative accesses can simply use the distance between the desired data and the designated special point as the offset.

On other archs everything is similar in principle, but there may be easier ways to load the program counter. Many simply let you use the `pc` or `ip` register as an ordinary register in relative addressing modes.

Comment: What does `call 1f ` mean here?

Comment: The next label `1:` in the `f`orward direction.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code it could look like:

```
lea str1(pc), r0 ; load address of string relative to the pc (assuming constant strings, maybe)
st r0, test  ; save the address in test (test could also be PIC, in which case it could be relative
             ; to some register)
```

A lot depends on your compiler and CPU architecture, as the previous answer stated. One way to find out would be to compile with the appropriate flags (-PIC -S for gcc) and look at the assembly language you get.