# Why I can't compile this assembly successfully?

Tags: assembly

Quoted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094934/loading-raw-code-from-c-program):

```
.text
    call start
    str:
        .string "test\n"
    start:
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    $1, %ebx
    pop     %ecx
    movl    $5, %edx
    int     $0x80
    ret
```

`gcc -c test.S` gives :

```
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:8: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
```

Answer (score 2):

pop is just the command. In at&t syntax you have to postpone the operand dimension. so you have to change the "pop" line with "popl"

**Edit**

1. The correct answer is the one by Jens Björnhager as on my 64 bit laptop your code get correctly assembled by specifying it is a 32 bit architecture.
2. The operand dimension is not mandatory but *strongly* advised.

Comment: @mysql_go you can find the answer here: http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html in the "64-bit instructions" paragraph. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably on a 64 bit system trying to compile 32-bit assembly. Force gcc to compile 32 bits with **-m32**:

```
gcc -m32 -c test.S
```

**Edit:**

64-bit version:

```
.text
    call start
    str:
        .string "test\n"
    start:
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $1, %edi
    popq    %rsi
    movl    $5, %edx
    syscall

    movl    $60,%eax
    movl    $0, %edi
    syscall
```

Comment: I thought all the 32bit instructions (including 16 bit ones) were still available on 64bit, but I was wrong. Here there is a webpage which explains why the popl instruction above doesn't work. http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html

Comment: it works,cool, but how can I use the output on a 64-bit machine? I tried to reproduce it using the output as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094934/loading-raw-code-from-c-program , but no it doesn't work.

Comment: That is 32-bit assembly, you need to rewrite everything to conform to the 64-bit ABI. I'm updating my answer with a x86-64 version of your program.

Comment: but many 32-bit programe can also be run on 64-bit machines,right?